# CNTK Python: Dense Layer output size doesn't match expecation?

Tags: cntk

I'm training the tutorials/language understanding model in CNTK/Python

```
def create_model():
    with C.layers.default_options(initial_state=0.1):
        return C.layers.Sequential([
            C.layers.Embedding(emb_dim, name='embed'),
            C.layers.Recurrence(C.layers.LSTM(hidden_dim), go_backwards=False),
            C.layers.Dense(num_labels, name='classify')
        ])

model = model_func(x)
```

For some reason,    model.eval(data)[0].shape is (2 * 16) not (1 * 16), where num_labels = 16. I'm very confused. Why is it  2 * 16 instead of 1 * 16, given the last layer is a dense layer with size = num_labels=16?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the `data` element that you are passing in has a shape (2, x), i.e. you are passing in multiple values for evaluation, so `eval()` is returning a prediction for each of the values you passed in to the model.